# Are there any sources about defiling and/or renouncing an idol being a capital offense?

Tags: source-request, iconography, pagan

Are there any sources about defiling and/or renouncing an idol in the ancient pagan world being a capital offense?

Comment: Any takers on this questions?

Comment: It seems like this concept relates to asebeia, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asebeia